# Accessing a WMS service with OpenLayers 7.1.0 with basic http authentication

Tags: http-headers, openlayers, basic-authentication, wms

I'm new to this world of web mapping and stuck in this problem.
I want to access the [ChartWorld WMS service](https://www.sevencs.com/chartserver/wms-chartserver/) using [OpenLayers](https://openlayers.org/).
I can access it from a specific IP address using this javaScript code and everything works fine:

```
const ENCIPLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
    source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
        ratio: 1,
        params: {LAYERS: 'ENC', CSBOOL: '2183', CSVALUE: '10,5,20,10,1,2,1,4000000,100000,200000,1'},
        url: 'https://wms.chartworld.com/?'
    })
});
```

But I don't know how to access the service using username/password and basic http authentication.
The address for this method is

```
https://wms-eval.chartworld.com
```

I searched a lot, but didn't find anything working !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a custom load function similar to the one documented in [https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Tile.html#~LoadFunction](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Tile.html#%7ELoadFunction) (tile source have a `tileLoadFunction`, image sources have a `imageLoadFunction`) and add a basic authentication header.  To conserve memory object urls should be revoked after use.

```
source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
    ratio: 1,
    params: {LAYERS: 'ENC', CSBOOL: '2183', CSVALUE: '10,5,20,10,1,2,1,4000000,100000,200000,1'},
    url: 'https://wms.chartworld.com/?',
    imageLoadFunction: function (image, src) {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.responseType = 'blob';
        xhr.open('GET', src);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + window.btoa(username + ':' + password));
        xhr.onload = function() {
            const url = URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
            const img = image.getImage();
            img.addEventListener('load', function() {
                URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            });
           img.src = url;
        };
        xhr.send();
    }
})
```

Comment: Dear Mike, Thank you so much. completely solved on first try.